# Using Celery in a single-app Django project

Tags: django, celery

I've structured my Django project according to the [Single-App Django Project Anatomy](https://zindilis.com/blog/2017/01/06/django-anatomy-for-single-app.html) pattern for simplicity. This gives me a project structure as follows:

```
myproject
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── celery.py
├── myapp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── views.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Further, I've created a celery.py containing initializing the app instance:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
app = Celery('myproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I do realise that Celery probably expects a "traditional" project structure for it's integration. What would be a correct celery.py setup in this case, and how should the worker be run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your **init**.py file to load the app when Django starts.
Add the code snippet  to modify '**init**.py' module

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Source: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Add some code explanation about link's content is preferred, since it may become invalid when time passing.

Comment: @keikai Thanks, have added the relevant content